# How to remove the "username@host" from powershell prompt?

Tags: powershell-4.0, posh-git, windows-terminal

I am using Windows Terminal(Preview) with shells like `1.PowerShell, 2.WSL` in my Windows 10 machine. I installed the latest version of `oh-my-posh` and `posh-git` to customize the terminal. My current theme is `Agnoster` which gives a colorful custom prompt. But I want to get rid of the "username@host" from my prompt.

**Eg:**

**Current** => *username@host* D:\folder-name>

**Needed** => D:\folder-name>

I tried few things with `$GitPromptSettings` variable and also in  `GitPrompt.ps1` file which is inside the posh-git folder but with no use.

Also, since i have oh-my-posh and posh-git, does both have prompt customization properties or it is only from posh-git?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

remove the segment which type is session from `~\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\oh-my-posh\3.101.23\themes\<themename>.omp.json`

Answer (score 7):

You have to set $DefaultUser before importing modules.

Example:

```
$global:DefaultUser = [System.Environment]::UserName
Import-Module posh-git 
Import-Module oh-my-posh
Set-Theme Paradox
```

Comment: OMG. Awesome. Thanks. It worked. But can you please explain what we are doing and how it is working? Because, i was thinking that, i should do something on the ```GitPrompt``` variable which is returned by posh.git

Comment: This is no longer working in Oh My Posh 3, see the answer by @cocoa2135 below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66740114/928483

Answer (score 6):

In **Oh My Posh 3**, the method for hiding the `username@host` part has changed because the whole theme configuration has changed.

The `username@host` portion of the powerline comes from the `"session"` segment. The configuration options for `session` can be found here: https://ohmyposh.dev/docs/session

Interesting options are:

- `display_user: boolean` - display the user name or not - defaults to `true`
- `display_host: boolean` - display the host name or not - defaults to `true`
- `default_user_name: string` - name of the default user - defaults to empty
- `display_default: boolean` - display the segment or not when the user matches `default_user_name` - defaults to `true`

And the note on environment variables:

> `POSH_SESSION_DEFAULT_USER` - used to override the hardcoded `default_user_name` property

### Solution

Based on this, I made the following changes:

1. For the theme, I added the `display_default: false` property to the `"session"` segment:

   ````
   {
     "type": "session",
     // ....
     "properties": {
       "display_default": false
     }
   }```
   ````
2. In my powershell profile, I set the new environment variable to my own username:
   `$env:POSH_SESSION_DEFAULT_USER = [System.Environment]::UserName`

This makes the `user@host` part of the prompt disappear as long as I'm using my default username.

Comment: It's not clear from your answer wether you need to do 1. and 2. or just either one of them. The default location of the theme files could also be mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You may check `{theme's name}.psm1` in the Themes/ directory to understand how it works.
The key is the following code.

e.g. Paradox.psm1

```
$user = $sl.CurrentUser
....
if (Test-NotDefaultUser($user)) {

        $prompt += Write-Prompt -Object "$user@$computer " -ForegroundColor $sl.Colors.SessionInfoForegroundColor -BackgroundColor $sl.Colors.SessionInfoBackgroundColor

}
```

if `$DefaultUser` is same to `$user` or is different `$null`, your powershell does not show `$user@$computer`.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I was going through the ```Agnoster.psm1``` file to understand the logic. Ii will be easy if i could debug the file. Seems there is a way to debug. Let me check. Thanks Again.